# Tailwindcss v3 and SvelteKit - Unable to reuse styles

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, sveltekit

First off, I'm completely out of ideas here. Read the docs, searched all over the internet but without luck. What I'm trying to achieve is to simply reuse styles for my form input elements. To do that, I'm defining the style within the `app.css` file of a SvelteKit app. The styles are defined according to the spec:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
    .ext-form-input {
        @apply placeholder:text-gray-400 invalid:[&:not(:placeholder-shown)] peer block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset invalid:text-error invalid:ring-error focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-blue focus:invalid:ring-error sm:text-sm sm:leading-6;
    }
}
```

When I know use this style within my Svelte file like `class="btn-primary"`, I get the following error:

> Internal server error: [postcss] path-to-file/src/app.css:7:9: The 'placeholder:text-gray-400' class does not exist. If 'placeholder:text-gray-400' is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a  '@layer' directive.

To rule out any issues with one of my used utility classes, I literally copied the example from the official documentation over. Same issue there but complains

> Internal server error: [postcss] path-to-file/src/app.css:7:9: The 'bg-blue-500' class does not exist. If 'bg-blue-500' is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a '@layer' directive.

Did anyone already have and solved this issue?

Comment: I believe You need to set custom styles in Your tailwind.config.cjs file

Comment: Thanks, will try. I saw that in the docs but what is the intention of using this `@apply` method at all? For me this is the perfect fit to do this - it's even written in the docs to be specifically designed for this sole purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out what caused this behavior. It turns out that I used custom theme colors that I defined in `tailwind.config.js`. It seems that tailwind is not able to infer those color definitions e.g. `text-primary-80` if they are used with `@apply although not explicitly mentioned in the docs (at least I didn't find it). I now use the full blown class names on each form input which feels kinda stupid in case because this will make refactoring or slight changes to a lot of form inputs very cumbersome...